# ASP.NET Core 2 + Get instance of db context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get an instance of the DbContext (so I can do some additional work upon startup with it), I get the following error when trying to get an instance in the Configure method:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'MyApp.Data.MyDbContext' from root provider.'

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{

    var dbContext = app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(MyDbContext)) as MyDbContext;
}
```

I can access an instance of the DbContext fine via the controller, etc

Comment: You can add dependencies to the Configure method and they will automatically get resolved. Try changing signature to public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, MyDbContext dbContext)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Paul Hiles comment is correct but that method works better in .NET Core 1.0.

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 it's generally a bad idea to run any database setup in `Startup.cs`. This is because if you run any migrations from the CLI or Visual Studio it will run all of `Startup.cs` and try to run your configuration which will fail. Of course if you don't use Entity-Framework then this isn't a problem however its still not the recommended way of doing it in 2.0. It's now recommended to do it in `Program.cs`.

For example you can create a extension method of `IWebHost` that will run any setup you need.

```
public static IWebHost MigrateDatabase(this IWebHost webHost)
{
    var serviceScopeFactory = (IServiceScopeFactory)webHost.Services.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory));

    using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<YourDbContext>();

        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }

    return webHost;
}
```

And then in `Program.cs` you can then call that method before running.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args)
        .MigrateDatabase()
        .Run();
}
```

Comment: ...and if you are keeping all your DbContext items in separate a class library? Is there a way to set it up for the Asp.Net Core 2 Web app?

Comment: Just sending you a comment to let you know this helped me big time with ASP.NET Core on Heroku. I wasn't able to run "heroku run dotnet ef database update", but I was able to use this code to have it run the migrations as it started up after I pushed to heroku master.

I wrapped it in an environment variable (checked for equal to "true") so that I could control whether or not it ran, just in case I needed to. Works well with Heroku's web dashboard.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when it doesn't answer the question? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 6):

#### Update for Core 2.1 onwards

Just to add to [@Travis Boatman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5107677/travis-boatman)'s excellent answer, the preferred `Main` method syntax has [changed slightly from Core 2.1 onwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/20_21?view=aspnetcore-2.2#changes-to-take-advantage-of-the-new-code-based-idioms-that-are-recommended-in-aspnet-core-21) and the default `Main` method now has `CreateWebHostBuilder` instead of `BuildWebHost`.

The revised code to call the extension method is shown below.

NB: the order is important here, the `Build` method returns a `WebHost`, which is what the extension method is extending, so you need to call the migrate method after `Build()` and before `Run()`):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
        .Build()
        .MigrateDatabase()
        .Run();
}
```

#### Migrating more than one DbContext

We have more than one `DbContext` in our project, so I changed the extension method to a generic method that can take any type of `DbContext`:

```
public static IWebHost MigrateDatabase<T>(this IWebHost webHost) where T:DbContext
{
    var serviceScopeFactory = (IServiceScopeFactory)webHost
        .Services.GetService(typeof(IServiceScopeFactory));

    using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

        var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<T>();
        dbContext.Database.Migrate();
    }

    return webHost;
}
```

You can then chain the calls to migrate the different contexts:

```
CreateWebHostBuilder(args)
    .Build()
    .MigrateDatabase<ApiAuthDbContext>()
    .MigrateDatabase<MainDbContext>()
    .MigrateDatabase<SomeOtherDbContext>()
    .Run();
```

Comment: CreateHostBuilder shows error " 'IHost' does not contain a definition for 'MigrateDatabase' and the best extension method overload 'Extensions.MigrateDatabase(IWebHost)' requires a receiver of type 'IWebHost' ".

Comment: Found the Solution, just change the MigrateDatabase method "IWebHost" to "IHost" and add "using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting".

Answer (score 0):

[see this question and he answerd himself in the 'Update' section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590579/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-from-root-provider-net-core-2)

Add in `program.cs` at `CreateWebHostBuilder` method

```
 .UseDefaultServiceProvider(options => {
     options.ValidateScopes = false;//to use any scoped
     option.validateOnBuild = false;//to use dbContext 
})
```

The full code:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    Host.CreateWebHostBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>  
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
            {
                options.ValidateScopes = false;
                option.ValidateOnBuild = false;
            });
        })
}
```