# .Net core DI Scope validation , scoped vs transient?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

Reading the [*docs*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#scope-validation) :

> When the app is running in the Development environment, the default
>   service provider performs checks to verify that:
>
> - Scoped services aren't directly or indirectly resolved from the root service provider.
> - **Scoped services aren't directly or indirectly injected into singletons**

This means that I shouldn't inject Scoped services into a singleton service.

Based on the fact that transient services creates an instance each time they're requested, VS scoped services which are single instances throughout the request's lifecycle :

**Question:**

Why does the DI only validate scoped services and not also transient services?

Comment: Why transient need to be validated. Transient instance can exists as long as singleton exists. Transient instance is not injected anywhere else, it exists only within singleton instance.

Comment: Fabio i still don't  understand why is it different for transient vs scoped. Can you please provide a problematic example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

From the  [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) the above describes why they do this check. To understand this better I started reading about the various lifetimes more being an autofac guy myself to understand the .net core flavor of registrations.

- The scoped registration entails a services lifetime being one
  instance per request(connection)
- Singleton has only a single state defined at time of registration or constructor run time.
  (in `startup.cs`)
- A transient is a new instance per constructor injection ie per
  dependency.

Generally you would us the singleton pattern to maintain perhaps some sort state in memory for your application lifetime etc, there are many use cases but the important thing to understand that the constructor of your singleton class (where you inject your dependencies) will **run once and only once** for your entire application lifetime.

You could imagine that injecting a scoped or transient service into singleton while baring the above in mind will lead to some ... unexpected results , you are expecting your service to adhere to its specific life time but in actual fact its really just the same instance every time due to the nature of the singleton.

To answer your question using my understanding : A transient injected into a singleton (while inherently not correct) will still function fine as its lifetime is short and runs of little risk of breaking state whereas scoped guarantees a lifetime across a single request (think some sort of request caching as an example), there is no way that scoped can honor that lifetime while being injected into a singleton.

Comment: How come? Singleton's constructor runs only once. And if i inject a transient service then it will never be released

Comment: The singleton pattern "restricts the instantiation of a class to one "single" instance", Therefore the constructor should only run once to satisfy this. A transient service will therefore always be in the same state as the singleton itself.

Comment: I know that already. Still the question remains. Why does injecting scoped is different over injecting transient. Why does the validation is only (!!) For scoped.

Comment: See the last part of my answer - a scoped registered object cannot guarantee its lifetime if it is injected into a singleton whereas a transient "can" it just becomes a singleton itself.

Comment: Ok I'm almost there. A transient becomes singleton. Yeah. But why does scoped not becomes a singleton also? Besides the given fact. It's logical to think that scoped will also be elevated to a singleton . So i guess that the only question is why does scopes not elevated. 

Comment: Lets assume you have a scoped service that stores the `GameId`(int) for a web request coming into your application - `GameService.cs`, at some point in your application the `GameId` changes because the user is underage and not allowed the play that game and redirected to another new game - you agree the `GameId` property changes in the `GameService`? If you injected the GameService into the singleton *the gameid will never change*. Microsoft wants to protect you from these mistakes by validating this. A transient service does not store state - hence why you dont have the problem.

Comment: The holy grail here is the last sentence. Transient shouldn't store state.  Ive missed that info. Now it all make sense. So transient doesn't store state and will become singleton if elevated  which could lead to a memory leak.  Its just that since scoped services store/can store state , they warn us from elevation.  Right?

Comment: The reason is more that if a service activation exists in the parent container, it will be taken from there and if not will be instantiated by the child container. When the child container is disposed, it disposes all of the services it instantiated. But if the application instantiated the scoped service it won't be disposed (effectively becoming a singleton). Thats why you want to prevent it being resolved in parent container.

Comment: Transient doesn't suffer it because its instantiated per activation (per resolve). If you have 2 services in a single request, both asking for `ITransientService`, then you will get two instances, even when you are in the same request. That's not something you want, if the state has to persist for the duration of the request. A transient service you an safely dispose, when you are done in your class, action or command. A scoped you can't cause other services later during that request on may still need it

Comment: @Tseng albeit your comment being more technically accurate I believe we are explaining similar things.