# How to inject mock services into WebApplicationFactory in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, integration-testing

I'm building up some integration tests and I'm using the `WebApplicationFactory` class to spin-up an in-memory version of my API.

I'm trying to add some services to my unit tests, and I'm following the guidance in MS docs. Unfortunately, once I try to fetch a required service, I am finding that the services are not registered in the service collection.

I've also tried looking at `_apiFactory.Server.Services` but it doesn't seem to contain the services either. Any ideas on this one?

```
public class MinimumCodeTests: IClassFixture<CustomApiFactory>
  {
    private readonly CustomApiFactory _apiFactory;

    public MinimumCodeTests(CustomApiFactoryapiFactory)
    {
      _apiFactory = apiFactory;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task SampleTest()
    {
      // Arrange

      var httpClient = _apiFactory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
      {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
          services.AddScoped<IServiceOne, ServiceOne>(); // Required by ServiceTwo
          services.AddScoped<IServiceTwo, ServiceTwo>();
        });
      }).CreateClient();

      var serviceTwo = _apiFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceTwo>(); // Does not work
    }
}
```

On calling  `var serviceTwo = _apiFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<IServiceTwo>();`, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot resolve scoped service 'DataAccess.Services.IEventService' from root provider.
```

EDIT: I've omitted some code that shows integration with data access layer/database for simplicity.

Comment: Is it an unit or an integration test?

Comment: I believe an integration test, as it tests interaction between my API, data access layer and DB. I've left out the call to the API to simplify the code.

Comment: You probably need to create a scope. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75390799/2599508

Comment: @sonodan Then please update your question to provide clarity. (n the question itself you are mentioning unit testing while in the title and in the tags you are using integration testing.

Comment: can you show CustomApiFactory? 
I guess its a wrapper for  WebApplicationFactory<T> 
then you could add your services in  the override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder) of  CustomApiFactory. Thats similar to what i did and it works.