# Access service during creation of IOC - ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application.

In my `program.cs` file, I'd like to load my system settings from my database and inject them as a singleton so that I can access them from controller constructors etc. Is it possible to access a service during IOC creation or is there a better way? Something like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DataContextConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MyAssembly"));
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>();

// Can I get an instance of ISettingsRepository (rep) here and use it to load system settings?
// e.g. 
// var rep = ???
// var settings = rep.GetSystemSetings();
// builder.Services.AddSingleton<SystemSettingsDto, settings>();
```

Comment: Personally I would think about creating a [custom configuration provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-configuration-provider). But you can always register an singleton which will create a custom scope and resolve the context and read all the needed data.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the service provider when registering the services in the container. You can use the following statement to achieve the things that you need:

```
builder.Services.AddTransient<ISettingsRepository, SettingsRepository>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<SystemSettingsDto>(provider => provider.GetService<ISettingsRepository>().GetSystemSetings());
```

Comment: Using your suggestion, The app builds Unfortunately, when I access any controller that needs systemsettings, I get error "Cannot resolve scoped service 'ISettingsRepository' from root provider."

Comment: Because the ISettingsRepository is registered as scoped, it cannot be injected into a singleton service, and seems is a standard error. To resolve this issue, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590579/cannot-resolve-scoped-service-from-root-provider-net-core-2) SO answer or register the ISettingsRepository as a "Transient" service.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to inject your repo into your respective class where you need this. And you may not access the Db everytime, so you can use MemoryCache to cache first time reading from Db and then on, rely on the cached value.

```cs
public class MyController {
    private readonly IAppSettingsRepo _appSettingsRepo;

    public MyController(IAppSettingsRepo repo) {
        _appSettingsRepo = repo;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        var settings = _appSettingsRepo.GetDbSettings();
        if (settings.WriteToFile) {
            // do something based on this system setting
        }
    }
}
```

And since its going to be pulling from Db, you can use Memcache to cache the db values into memory or explore using external caching like redis etc.

```cs
public interface ICacheBase
    {
        Task<TItem> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(object key, Func<Task<TItem>> createItem);
        Task ClearItemFromCacheAsync(object key);
    }

public class AppMemCache : ICacheBase
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;
    private MemoryCacheEntryOptions _cacheOptions;
    private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appConfig;

    public AppMemCache(IMemoryCache cache, IOptions<AppSettings> appConfig)
    {
        _cache = cache;
        _appConfig = appConfig;
        _cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.Parse(_appConfig.Value.MaxCacheDuration),
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.Parse(_appConfig.Value.ItemCacheDuration)
        };
    }
    #region ICacheBase implementations
    public async Task ClearItemFromCacheAsync(object key)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => _cache.Remove(key));
    }

    public async Task<TItem> GetOrCreateAsync<TItem>(object key, Func<Task<TItem>> createItem)
    {
        TItem cacheEntry;
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(key, out cacheEntry))
        {
            // Key not in cache, so get data.
            cacheEntry = await createItem();

            // Save data in cache.
            _cache.Set(key, cacheEntry, _cacheOptions);
        }
        return cacheEntry;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And your DI can look like,

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IAppSettingsRepo, YourActualRepoImplementation>();
services.AddMemoryCache();
services.AddSingleton<ICacheBase, AppMemCache>();
```

Not saying this is the solution, but this is one solution to your need. There are other ideas you can certainly explore for your usecase like, I may have read the db settings and cache them to an external cache like redis. So the depending class/controller or whatever it is, would inject the ICacheBase, which would have the DI to implement the Redis caching instead of mem cache and that will be available as persistent way and not required to make db calls everytime and not needing to keep in memory. Or if its not required to be complicated, in-memory cache will settle the requirements too.

There is another thought that can go into the broader view as to, do we need to maintain the settings in the db or a config file can do, or Environment variables, secrets store etc. And even the db store for settings can be simply a key-value db like redis unlike to be under a DBMS.

All these comments are to provoke your own ideation and implementation since there is no one right answer/solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

This works. I assume that by implementing 'using' the scope will be destroyed. Is there any danger of this code creating dual instances of singletons or other issues ?

```
var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
using (var scope = provider.CreateScope())
{
    var rep = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ISettingsRepository>();
    var settings = await rep.GetSystemSettingsAsync();
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<SystemSettingsDto>(settings);
}
```